# Single page application search and pagination out of sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, ecmascript-6

My webapp has a pagination and filter bug. It's basically out of sync. Both features worked independently, but when we put search and pagination together and play with it back and forth I noticed something is not right.

I search a query, the server return 50 item. Since I have pagination that limit 10 per page, it shows 10 as the result. When I clicked to the next page, my query state is gone. It's not intuitive to the users. How do I solve this problem? Also the user can click on the pagination first then enter the search box.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you provide enough technical details (usually including code to reproduce your issue) for people to be able to understand your situation and provide you with relevant help. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), provides some guidance.

Comment: @david this is behavior bug, I'm not going paste the entire thing here.

Comment: You don't have to copy/paste the entire thing here, just the relevant pagination parts you've traced the bug to. We can't really help if the question is just "my pagination doesn't work, how do i fix it?". It's going to depend on your implementation. Also, for your problem description, what does "my query state is gone" mean specifically?